# pandas| fill avg to cells based on the categories they belong to

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Here is the example dataframe:

```
ID     Name       occupation   salary
1      p1             O1        1000
2      p2             O2        2000
3      p3             O3        4000
4      p4             O1        1500
5      p5             O1        
6      p6             O2        2100 
7      p7             O1        -9999
8      p8             O2
```

How can I detect all invalid values(missing & negative salary) and fill avg salaries of their belonged occupation to those cells?

Output:

```
ID     Name       occupation   salary
1      p1             O1        1000
2      p2             O2        2000
3      p3             O3        4000
4      p4             O1        1500
5      p5             O1        1250
6      p6             O2        2100 
7      p7             O1        1250
8      p8             O2        2050
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
sal=df['salary'].where(df['salary'].gt(0))
df['salary'] = sal.fillna(sal.groupby(df['occupation']).transform('mean'))
df
```

Output:

```
   ID Name occupation  salary
0   1   p1         O1  1000.0
1   2   p2         O2  2000.0
2   3   p3         O3  4000.0
3   4   p4         O1  1500.0
4   5   p5         O1  1250.0
5   6   p6         O2  2100.0
6   7   p7         O1  1250.0
7   8   p8         O2  2050.0
```

Details, use `where` to return on only "valid" (greater than zero) salary, and put NaN for other values.  Next, `fillna` with the `groupby`, `transform`, `mean`.